# make variables that depend on a target

Tags: makefile

I have a Variable in make that is dependant on a file that must be built before the variable can be set, is there a way to get this to work?

```
parsable_file: dependancies
    commands to make parsable_file
targets=$(shell parse_cmd parsable_file)
$(targets): parsable_file
    command to make targets
.phony: all
all:$(targets)
```

If I run `$ make parsable_file && make all` this will work (I get an error that `parse_cmd` cant find `parsable_file` but it works), but just make all will not work. Is there a Make idiom for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the variable in a file that you `include` in the main makefile and include a rule in the main makefile for how to build it (the one you already have should be fine).

I believe that will do what you want.

See [Including Other Makefiles](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Include) and [How Makefiles Are Remade](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles) (which is linked from the first section) for more details on this concept.

Also, unless `parseable_file` has a usage independent from that `parse_cmd` call, it should be possible to do the creation and the parsing at the same time and just have the resulting makefile contain the correct value for `$(targets)` in one step.

Comment: thanks, I suppose there is no way to avoid making another file?

Comment: You could do the file creation (and possibly the variable setting) with a shell call early in the makefile if you wanted to but I'm not sure that's better (and makes using dependency-based tracking of regeneration of the file manual).